# HDMI audio profile off is only option

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, amd-graphics

Audio RS880 Mobile GPU 4200 ATI from laptop, using kubuntu 20.04.

Trying to enable it, the only option I get is off nothing else.

I installed pulse audio which then gives new options, under pulse they all say not plug-in, and yet HDMI is plug has been plugged in.

I manually select the 1st option on the HDMI, it gets added as an option in audio output and it works.

When I change a page in Firefox browser it switches back to using laptop speakers, and have to manually select HDMI again.

It won't stay using HDMI. Also when I restart laptop, I have to go back into pulse to manually re select HDMI to add back to the audio output to select it again.

I'm trying to make RS880 enable instead of showing as off only in audio settings.

I heard I can get an AMD proprietary driver 13.1 and install it.

No idea how to do this, and would like some help. I know I have to redo this if there is a kernel update, but I wouldn't mind as long if this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found an answer or given up but I encountered similar issue (only profile Off available when listing sinks) and this is one of first results in search engine.
What helped me was this post: [https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/1252]

Namely this part:

> If I remember correctly, there's two PipeWire and one WirePlumber
> issues I had on my system with ALSA userland 1.2.5:
>
> alsa-lib 1.2.5 made HDMI's HDA adapter either disappear completely or
> to have no profiles at all or maybe to only have the Off profile (my
> memory is a bit hazy on this a day later); this cleared as soon as I
> downgraded alsa-lib back to 1.2.4 and did systemctl --user restart
> pipewire{,-pulse,-media-session}.service . This matches the issue
> reported originally. alsa-ucm-conf 1.2.5 even with alsa-lib 1.2.4
> additionally caused the issue described by @lnicola where the HDMI
> device would only have Off and Pro Audio profiles. Cleared by
> downgrading alsa-ucm-conf to 1.2.4 and again restarting the daemons.
> WirePlumber always SIGABRTs if alsa-topology-conf 1.2.5 is installed
> but as noted by @gkiagia  it could be a continuation with route setup
> issue I have had since before. Downgrading to alsa-topology-conf 1.2.4
> stops the SIGABRT but WirePlumber still has [new] issues (maybe
> related to changes in WirePlumber git master?)

What I did was downgrade alsa-lib and lib32-alsa-lib to version 1.2.4 and restart services like in step 1 there. Audio through hdmi suddenly started working without any issues. Not guaranteed to work in your case (or anyone who finds this post like I did) but worth trying.